# Dynamic variables in angular2 / javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I have multiple download buttons on a page, with a progress bar for each download:

```
<progress-bar *ngIf="progressbar" [progress]="loadProgress_id1"></progress-bar>
<progress-bar *ngIf="progressbar" [progress]="loadProgress_id2"></progress-bar>
```

...

I have a function that sets the progress:

```
setpercentage(perc,id) {
    this.loadProgress_+id = Math.round(perc); // --> how could I do this?
    this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```

What I've tried (the above) doesn't work. How could I achieve this? Or should I use a different approach?

Comment: `this['loadProgress' + id] =`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
setpercentage(perc,id) {
    this['loadProgress_' + id] = ....
}
```

or

```
setpercentage(perc,id) {
    const prop = 'loadProgress_' + id;
    this[prop] = ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason an array wouldn't work for this?

// Html

```
<progress-bar 
  *ngFor="let progress of progressBars" 
  [progress]="progress"
></progress-bar>
```

// Ts

```
progressBars: number[] = [0,0];

setpercentage(perc,id) {
  this.progressBars[id] = Math.round(perc);
  this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```